# Who played the Oz head in the "Wizard of Oz"?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz

At the conclusion of 1939's "Wizard of Oz", the party of travelers finally gets an audience with the great and terrible Wizard of Oz, a huge, disembodied head given to imperious, bellowing pronouncements. Who played this strange character?

[image: Wizard of Oz head]

Comment: What makes you think its not Frank Morgan who is credited as Oz?  The facial features are somewhat similar to the Oz who is "behind the curtain".

Comment: With a different disguise, The Gatekeeper is also played by Frank Morgan.

Comment: Really? That's Frank Morgan? Are you sure?

Comment: Upon further review...  There's no indication he played the disembodied head.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si-elY_pvLY

Comment: I always assumed it was animation rather than a physical actor.

Comment: @TylerDurden .... no, I'm not sure at all, I just asked why you didn't think it was the credited actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20080524211727/http://www.preservehollywood.org/DungeonWebNew/In%20The%20Blood.html
This archive states Hull was a great make up artist. He created his own character as Jeeter Lester, in Tabacco Rd. and did his own make up when he portrayed Edgar Allen Poe. It suggests he embraced macabre rolls.

Comment: He also appeared with Judy Garland in "Babes in Arms" (1939).

Comment: His signature roll was, "The Warewolf of London" 1935, where his transformation from man to warewolf is still today among the best special effects of that era.

Comment: It seems like this should be edited into your other answer instead of being posted separately?

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you believe the [Wizard of Oz blog](http://www.thewizardofozblog.com/2014/11/frank-morgan-the-wonderful-wizard-of-oz-a-guest-blog-post-by-jay-scarfone-and-william-stillman-.html) (about 2/3rds of the way down the page) it states that:

> the face was that of an anonymous actor in heavy make-up, lip synching to Morgan’s dialogue.

I can find no other source of information online, and being that everyone involved with the production is long gone I don't think you're going to find much else that answers this question conclusively.

Comment: Hmmm, an anonymous actor.

Comment: Unfortunately, credits weren't as detailed back then, and apparently no one ever laid claim to being "the giant green head".  The movie is 78 years old now, and anyone who acted in it is either gone or has a sketchy memory at best.

Comment: "being that everyone involved with the production is long gone" -- [Gerard Marenghi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Maren), who was a member of the Lollipop Guild, is still with us at 97, but I doubt he knows.

Answer (score 0):

The face resembles Henry Hull who acted with Frank Morgan, the year before Oz,in the film *Romance For Three (1938)*.

Henry Hull appeared in nine films in 1939. If it is him, credit for the roll of the oracle head, in Oz may have been over looked as unimportant. In the early 1930s he was noted as an accomplished makeup artist in his Broadway rolls as Jetter Lester in "Tabacco Road" and as Edgar Allen Poe. His roll as "The Warewolf Of London" (1935)indicates his tallant in special effects makeup. He also appeared with Judy Garland, in "Babes In Arms" (1939)

Comment: It looks like speculation. Please back up your answer with credible sources.

Comment: Wikipedia filmography for Henry Hull, Frank Morgan, in Romance For Three, 1938. Also 9 film credits for 1939. No mention of Wizard Of Oz.